# Angular Grid randomly blank

Tags: angular, grid

In Angular we are populating grid with Ms sq api.
The grid is populating correctly.

In some random scenario the grid is blank.
We are not able to find are reproduce it.

I tried debugging and the api is returning data.

Any suggestions.

Comment: can you share some code sample/slackblitz? It will be easy to troubleshoot and assist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.